How can I completely close the browser when I click on X on Macos
I have edited the code in the chromium source code in the following file
chrome/browser/chrome_browser_application_mac.mm

- (void)terminate:(id)sender {
  [NSApp terminate:nil];
  [AppController.sharedController tryToTerminateApplication:self];
  // Return, don't exit. The application is responsible for exiting on its own.
}

However, after building the MacM and MacIntel versions, it only completely shuts down the browser on MacM, but on MacIntel it does not turn off but remains in the taskbar.
What code should I fix so I can completely shut down the browser when clicking x on macIntel

I would recommend debugging. I do Chromium development on Windows only, so can't precisely answer your question for mac version.
